# Random cropping images from data generators

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, crop

I have found this code for doing random cropping on images for tensorflow backend.

```
def random_crop(img, random_crop_size)
    # Note: image_data_format is 'channel_last'
    assert img.shape[2] == 3
    height, width = img.shape[0], img.shape[2]
    dy, dx = random_crop_size
    x = np.random.randint(0, width - dx + 1)
    y = np.random.randint(0, height - dy + 1)
    return img[y:(y+dy), x:(x+dx), :]
def crop_generator(batches, crop_length):
    while True:
        batch_x, batch_y = next(batches)
        batch_crops = np.zeros((batch_x.shape[0], crop_length, crop_length, 3))
        for i in range(batch_x.shape[0]):
            batch_crops[i] = random_crop(batch_x[i], (crop_length, crop_length))
        yield (batch_crops, batch_y)
```

In my case, I want to crop images with shape `(256,256,3)` into `(224,224,3)`. In `imagenes_trigo` every item is a string that contains the path of an image. I have generated my data with the `class PantasTrigoDataset`. How can I use the above image code for cropping every image of `data_train` and `data_valid`? It would be great if someone helps me. Thanks.

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(imagenes_trigo,labels,test_size=0.25)

class PlantasTrigoDataset(Sequence):
    def __init__(self,imagenes_trigo,labels):
        self.x=[imread(i) for i in tqdm(imagenes_trigo)]
        self.y=labels
        self.batch_size=8
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x)/float(self.batch_size)))
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        return np.array([file_name for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
    def get_steps(self):
        return len(self.x)//self.batch_size

data_train = PlantasTrigoDataset(x_train,y_train)
data_val = PlantasTrigoDataset(x_test,y_test)
```

I have tried this:

```
train_crops = crop_generator(data_train, crop_length)
valid_crops = crop_generator(data_val, crop_length)
```

but when I fit a model like this:

```
model.fit_generator(
                train_crops,
                steps_per_epoch= 2245,
                epochs=500,
                validation_data=valid_crops,
                validation_steps=748,
                callbacks=[csv_logger,checkpoint])
```

I get this error:

```
File "/home/jokin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 658, in _data_generator_task
generator_output = next(self._generator)

File "/home/jokin/PycharmProjects/TFG/PLANTS DISEASE/plants.py", line 106, in crop_generator
batch_x, batch_y = next(batches)
TypeError: 'PlantasTrigoDataset' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: In the above code you've found, batches argument in crop_generator function is an iterator. And next() is some function that gets the next batch from this iterator. So you need to find where and how these iterator and next() is defined, from the source where you found the code. And that is clearly what your error says - in place of an iterator, you're passing a class-object as an argument.